# Adding "maxRequestLenght" parameter causes internal server error in SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I am trying to run a report in SSRS 2016. After running the report, it throws "Maximum request lenght exceeded".

So, I've found a possoble solution as to put "maxRequestLenght" into web.config file in Report Server directory.

I've changed this line to the following:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLenght="10000" />
```

and restarted the Reporting Services service (in Reporting Services Configuration Manager).

After restart I am trying to run the report again and I am getting "HTTP 500 The website cannot display the page"

[image]

Restarting SQL, rerstarting SSRS, restarting Windows didnt help

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to send a large number of values for a multivalue parameters? URLS have a maximum length, and it sounds like you're exceeding that.

Comment: So what is the maximum value? I've even put maxRequestLenght="10" and it still crashes :(

Comment: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/417142/3484879)

Comment: Thanks for this, but it isn't really helpful. maxRequestLengh="1" also causes error. No matter what value I put there, it crashes

Comment: Could it be that `maxRequestLenght="10000"` `maxRequestLength` is spelled wrong?

Comment: It is from Microsoft site, letter by letter